# memory fault in lsof

Tags: aix, lsof, core-dump

I am trying to check a port with lsof: `lsof -i :443`

but it gives me an error message that says:

> /usr/local/bin/lsof[30]: 6226000 Memory fault(coredump)

Why is this happening, and how can I solve this?

Comment: does `lsof -v` indicate that it was compiled for your version of AIX? See the `-DAIXV` value compared with `oslevel`

Answer (score 2):

Either your RAM memory, the lsof binary  or corresponding libraries are corrupted.

Reinstall your lsof.